# UDP broadcast cannot work after network changed?

Tags: c#, wireshark, broadcast

**[Precodition]**

PC1(Windows):
LAN Address: 10.0.1.11
WiFi Address: 10.0.1.10

PC2(Windows)：
WiFi Address: 10.0.1.4

**[Step by step what I did and what the result I got]**

1. Start PC1 with WiFi disabled and LAN enabled, and I confirmed the IPAddress was 10.0.1.11
2. Start PC2 with WiFi enabled and I confirmed the IPAddress was 10.0.1.4
3. Start an UDP broadcast program (it was also receiving the UDP answer package from other PC within the same LAN) on PC1; and start the UDP receiver on PC2 (it also replied to the broadcast sender when received the broadcast message)
4. Start Wireshark on PC1 and capture the network packages.
5. Confirmed on PC1, it received the response message from PC2.
6. Disabled the LAN on PC1 and enabled the WiFi on it. and confirmed the IPAddress was changed to 10.0.1.10 (the WiFi interface) during the UDP broadcast program was running.
7. After a while, I confirm the result on PC1, it COULD NOT receive any UDP response from PC2. and I also confirmed the Wireshark packages, and **CANNOT** find any broadcast message sent from PC1 (whichever with the filter "ip.proto==UDP && ip.src==10.0.1.10" or "ip.proto==UDP && ip.src==10.0.1.11" !). But

The source code for **sending broadcast message** is shown as blew:

```
Socket sendSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

// Use GetHostAddresses() to enumerate the local IPAddress
string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
var addressList = Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostName);
foreach (var ip in addressList)
{
    if (ip.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetwork) { continue; }
    IPEndPoint ep = null;
    IPAddress ipSend = null;
    ipSend = IPAddress.Parse(ip.ToString());
    ipSend.Address |= 0xFF000000;
    ep = new IPEndPoint(ipSend, 1020);
    sendSocket.SendTo(broadcastMessage, ep);
}

//Use GetAllNetworkInterfaces() to enumerate the local IPAddress
NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in nics)
{
  if (adapter.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet ||
      adapter.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211)
  {
    IPInterfaceProperties ip = adapter.GetIPProperties();
    UnicastIPAddressInformationCollection ipCollection = ip.UnicastAddresses;
    foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ipadd in ipCollection)
    {
      if (ipadd.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
      {
        IPEndPoint ep = null;
        IPAddress ipSend = null;
        ipSend = IPAddress.Parse(ipadd.Address.ToString());
        ipSend.Address |= 0xFF000000;
        ep = new IPEndPoint(ipSend, 1020);
        sendSocket.SendTo(broadcastMessage, ep);
      }
    }
  }
}

//Use GetHostEntry() to enumerate the local IPAddress
IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName, AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
{
  IPEndPoint ep = null;
  IPAddress ipSend = null;
  ipSend = IPAddress.Parse(ip.ToString());
  ipSend.Address |= 0xFF000000;
  ep = new IPEndPoint(ipSend, 1020);
  sendSocket.SendTo(broadcastMessage, ep);
}
```

I tried 3 methods to enumerate local IPAddresses and then made the broadcast address. But they failed all.

8. I also checked the log on PC1 for UDP receiver part. And it was very strange that I could find the **10.0.1.11 (The LAN interface IP of PC1)** response the broadcast after I changed the network interface from LAN to WiFi on PC1. **(As my understand, the LAN of PC1 HAS BEEN DISABLED!)**

**It seems that, the broadcast message called by SendTo() api DIDNOT passthrough the TCP layer on PC1 (otherwise, the Wireshark packages will have the information) after the network changed from LAN to Wifi.**

Your guys have any information about this issue ? thanks a lot in advance.

The UDP receiver source code is shown as blew.

```
socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, 1);
socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1020));
socket.ReceiveTimeout = 100;
_udpReceiver = new UdpClient{Client = socket};
_udpReceiver.Client.ReceiveBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;

endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
while (!_stopReceiveEvent.WaitOne(1))
{
  byte[] rawBytes = _udpReceiver.Receive(ref endPoint);
  if (rawBytes.Length <= 0){ continue; }
  string receivedDeviceIPAddr = endPoint.Address.ToString();
  Console.WriteLine($"Recieve UDP response from {receivedDeviceIPAddr} : {endPoint.Port}");
}
```

Comment: Before network changed, PC1 could receive the UDP response from PC2, but it failed after network changed.

Comment: `Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName,` why are you doing this, why not just use `IPAddress.Any` for the local endpoint and let the system work out which adapter to use.

Comment: Thanks Charlieface(https://stackoverflow.com/users/14868997/charlieface). I tried the follow method and it worked now.


UdpClient udpSend = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0));

IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, _remoteUdpPort);

udpSend.Send(broadcastMessage, broadcastMessage.Length, endPoint);

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mess around with DNS names and the hostname.

Instead send the broadcast from `IPAddress.Any`, and send it to `IPAddress.Broadcast`.

The operating system will pick the most appropriate adapter and originating address to make that transmit.